# Too high latency while trying to manipulate sound arrays using sounddevice in python

Tags: python, numpy, low-latency, python-sounddevice

Few days ago, I have installed [a sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/) library in Python 2.7.5. I'm trying to make a sound array and add some effects to it immediately after I push a key on my MIDI controller. But I get a huge delay of 0.1 to 0.2 second which makes my code useless:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
import time
import math

#we're making a sound array with a 5 seconds length noisy sound and playing it:
duration=5
framerate = 44100
array=0.02*np.random.uniform(-1, 1, framerate*duration)
sd.play(array, framerate)

t=time.time()
while(True):
    signal=raw_input("push ENTER to hear a beep")
    start_iter=int(framerate*(time.time()-t))
    end_iter=min(start_iter+framerate/4, len(array))

    #we're trying to change our data array and play a beep signal of 0.25 second after each ENTER press instantly
    for i in range(start_iter, end_iter):
        array[i]=0.05*math.sin(440*2*math.pi*i/44100.)
    if end_iter==len(array): break #safe exit of a process after 5 seconds has passed
```

To keep it simple, my sound array is just a noisy sound and my effect consists of a 440Hz beep. I used raw_input() here (type "input()" in Python 3.x) instead of MIDI inputs which could be possible using Pygame library. My code works but each time we press ENTER we will hear a short delay before beep signal.
Is it possible to eliminate it? If not, any other libraries allowing to play a sound stream with no delays live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the desired latency with [sounddevice.default.latency](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.default.latency). Note however, that this is a *suggested* latency, the actual latency may be different, depending on the hardware and probably also on the host API. You can get an estimate of the actual latency with [sounddevice.Stream.latency](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.Stream.latency).

By default, the `sounddevice` module uses PortAudio's *high* latency setting in the hope to provide more robust behavior. You can switch it to PortAudio's *low* setting, or you can try whatever numeric value (in seconds) you want.

```
import sounddevice as sd
sd.default.latency = 'low'
```

Alternatively, you can of course also use the `latency` argument of `play()` etc.

If you want to have more control over the time, you might want to write your own custom callback function. There you can use the `time` argument, and outside of the callback function you can use [sounddevice.Stream.time](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.Stream.time).

You can also try to start a stream without using the `callback` argument and then use [sounddevice.Stream.write()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.Stream.write) on it. I don't know what that will do to the latency, but it might be worth a try.

Regarding other libraries, since you seem to be using PyGame already, you might also use it for the audio output. It might or might not have a different latency.

BTW, I don't know if your code is thread-safe since you are manipulating the array while the callback gives the memory addresses to PortAudio. It's probably not a good idea to implement it like this.